# Return data between geocoding api and google map is diffrent

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I use geocoding api check the address,but sometime it does not works.
A place I can find it in google maps, such as,

```
https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode&q=United+States+Florida++33016+Hialeah+Gardens+8038+NW+103rd+St,Unit+39+Miami+Cores++
```

but it returns 'ZERO_RESULTS' when I use geocoding api to check the address,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=United+States+Florida++33016+Hialeah+Gardens+8038+NW+103rd+St,Unit+39+Miami+Cores++&sensor=true

{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Maybe the data between google map and geocoding api is diffrent.
Or I use the geocoding api in a wrong way,format the address?

Comment: The geocoder handles **postal addresses**.   [nited States Florida 33016 Hialeah Gardens 8038 NW 103rd St,Unit 39 Miami Cores](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=United+States+Florida+33016+Hialeah+Gardens+8038+NW+103rd+St,Unit+39+Miami+Cores&place=1) isn't a postal address (it does contain one), it is a **place**.  See [geocoding best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices)

Comment: Thx.  And who do you know isn't a postal address,but a place? As a api user , we have a address string only (named place or postal addresses?) .

Comment: "Unit 39 Miami Cores" confuses the geocoder.  If [I remove that}(http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=United+States+Florida+33016+Hialeah+Gardens+8038+NW+103rd+St&geocode=1) the geocoder can find the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google GeoCoding API - returns ZERO\_RESULTS but the location shows on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500751/google-geocoding-api-returns-zero-results-but-the-location-shows-on-google-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to find business Miami Cores Inc using Geocoding API.

Please note that Geocoding API works only with street addresses, all business results are out of the scope.

In case when your intention is to search a business, Places API is the best option.

E.g.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=8038%20NW%20103rd%20St%2C%20Hialeah%20Gardens%2C%20FL%2033016&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 1):

This should work now, since [Issue 10585](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10585) has been fixed:

Query: United States Florida 33016 Hialeah Gardens 8038 NW 103rd St, Unit 39 Miami Cores
Result: 8038 NW 103rd St, Hialeah Gardens, FL 33016, USA ([source](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DUnited%2520States%2520Florida%252033016%2520Hialeah%2520Gardens%25208038%2520NW%2520103rd%2520St%252C%2520Unit%252039%2520Miami%2520Cores%26nfw%3D1), [API request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=United%20States%20Florida%2033016%20Hialeah%20Gardens%208038%20NW%20103rd%20St%2C%20Unit%2039%20Miami%20Cores))

The [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) will find the same result as Google Maps, but return only the **address** of the place. If you need business names, phone numbers, etc. you'll need to use the Places API ([Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) or [Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)) instead.

However, I wouldn't count on Google Maps APIs to always understand your backwards query, your query terms are in the reverse than usual order. You may want to adhere to the following to get better results:

- [How should I format my geocoder queries to maximise the number of successful requests?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat)
- [Best Practices When Geocoding Addresses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices)