# Google GeoCoding API - returns ZERO_RESULTS but the location shows on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am using Google GeoCode API to search a location from an address and get LAT, LON information of that location.

From the API I always get `ZERO_RESULTS` where as if I search the address from the Google Maps, It shows me the location

The address I search for is,

`5989 Route 6N, Edinboro, Pennsylvania, 16412, United States`

Below given is the request that I sent to Google API,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5989%20Route%206N%20Edinboro%20Pennsylvania%20United%20States%2016412&key={{API_KEY}}`

Can anyone help me on resolving this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a result for that address with the [geocoder](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=102%20Route%206N%20Edinboro%20Pennsylvania%20United%20States%2016412&geocode=1), the [places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=102%20Route%206N%20Edinboro%20Pennsylvania%20United%20States%2016412&place=1) or [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/102+Route+6N+Edinboro+Pennsylvania+United+States+16412/@40.5802143,-74.5404692,15z).  Please provide an example where you get a response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated another address.

Comment: The new address is a [place entry on Google maps (Camboro Veterinary Hospital)](https://www.google.com/maps/place//data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x8b5d46f4e9a3eca9?hl=en&nogmmr=1), there is no entry in the geocoding database for that location

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip

Comment: Is the Places API always have a good data set than GeoCode API?

Comment: They have different purposes. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google geocode API can't find address returned by the place API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370414/google-geocode-api-cant-find-address-returned-by-the-place-api)

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue in the Geocoding API: [Issue 11031](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11031).

It has been fixed as of this week, so that Geocoding API will always return the same result/s as Google Maps:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5989%20Route%206N%20Edinboro%20Pennsylvania%20United%20States%2016412

```
 "formatted_address" : "5989 Route 6n, Edinboro, PA 16412, USA",
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like what that issue was about. People were having problems months ago in the issue and it seemed to be about addresses that previously worked in the geocode API suddenly not working or addresses with extra info (like Suite 107) not working. I didn't see anyone say that the geocode API will now return the same results as google maps, it seems like there can still be addresses that resolve in the maps/places api, but not in geocode.

Comment: People would have been having this problem since the end of November, 2016, due to the new forward geocoder becoming the default in the Geocoding API for unidentified requests and Standard Plan customers, as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq#default ─ the new geocoder did not initially return exactly the same results as Google Maps, it would drop results that were business listings, and not return an alternative address-only result, and that's exactly what Issue 10585 was all about.

Comment: Sorry! Huge apologies for the worst typo I've had in months: it was Issue 11031 that this was all about, nothing to do with Issue 10585. I've no idea how I got that mixed up, sorry!