# Google Places API returns 'ZERO_RESULTS' but Google Maps has results

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to make a simple phone-number checker using Python and Google Places API.
Search phone numbers and see if each number is registered on Google Maps, that's all.
But it seems Places API returns different results from manual web searching.

(My location is South Korea)

If you search '070-4596-3690' on a Google Maps, you got 1 result. [(the result page)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%EC%9E%90%EB%8F%99%EC%B0%A8%ED%83%81%EC%86%A1/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x357b5af300000001:0xe2b5948557c19ee3!8m2!3d37.2833789!4d127.1017312!16s%2Fg%2F1q5br00hr)

But when I try Places API like below, it returns 'ZERO_RESULTS'. How can I get a correct result? There are many similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500751/google-geocoding-api-returns-zero-results-but-the-location-shows-on-google-map) but nothing solved the problem.

```
import json
import googlemaps
from googlemaps.places import find_place

api_key = 'API_KEY'

client = googlemaps.Client(key=api_key)

response = find_place(
    client,
    '+827045963690',
    'phonenumber', # 'textquery' also return ZERO_RESULTS
    ['place_id',],
    
    # 'location_bias' was not helpful
    # location_bias='circle:100000@35.5373332,128.1012428'
    # location_bias='rectangle:32.967717951112654,125.60777420336103|38.75028515307909,129.65074281706745'
    # location_bias='rectangle:37.2814481,127.0967687|37.2918108,127.107755'
)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
'''
{
    "candidates": [],
    "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
'''
```

Comment: Google Maps and the Google Maps Places API are different things.   Google Maps includes additional data sources not available in the Places API.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the Python library is not URL-encoding the `+` sign in the phone number (as `%2B`). Without that URL-encoding, the `+` is equivalent to a blank space, which makes the query *not* be an internal-format phone number.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=+827045963690 returns `ZERO_RESULTS`

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%2B827045963690 returns `ChIJAQAAAPNaezUR457BV4WUteI` with `international_phone_number: "+82 70-4596-3690"`.

To confirm whether this is the problem, try with

```
response = find_place(
    client,
    '+827045963690',
    'phonenumber', # 'textquery' also return ZERO_RESULTS
    ['place_id',],
)
```

And if that is confirmed to be the issue, file a bug for the Python library to URL-encode `+` signs in the values of URL parameters for the Maps APIs.